# Order/Invoice/Payment database modeling

Tags: database, database-design, e-commerce, payment, invoice

I am designing an e-commerce website that has the following scenario:

1. A customer can purchase items and create an order.
2. The order may have unknown fee that will be added after the customer
   pays the total amount of the items. That is, the customer pays
   certain amount first. The order adds some fee and changes the total.
   And the customer pays again for the difference. But the two (or
   more) payments are associated with the same order.
3. (Optional) The customer can submit a single payment for multiple
   orders.

Currently, I have an `Order` table and each order may consist of multiple `OrderLineItem`s (simplified schema):

```
Order
=====
customer
line_items
total
status

OrderLineItem
=============
price
quantity
order
product
```

A payment is associated with an order (simplified schema):

```
Payment
=======
order
payment_account
total
result
```

It seems to be very hard to support the multiple payments for a single order scenario in the current implementation. I reckon that I have to introduce immutable invoices in the system, and the payment should be associated with an invoice instead of an order. However, I would need some help with the order/invoice/payment modeling for the above scenario. Some specific questions I have:

1. An order and an invoice look very similar to me (e.g. both have
   items and totals). What is the major difference in typical
   e-commerce systems?
2. How should I model invoices for my scenario? Should I have
   `OrderLineItem`s for an `Order` AND `InvoiceLineItem`s for an `Invoice`?
3. Some preliminary thoughts: I will have multiple invoices associated
   with a certain order. Whenever the order changes the total, I have
   to somehow calculate the difference and send a new/immutable invoice
   to the customer. Then, the customer can pay and the payment will be
   associated with the invoice.

Would love to hear some advice. Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: payment and invoice is many to many. user can make many payments on one invoice or make one payment against several invoices. you need a policy (business rule) to figure out how to apply payments in line with company rules

Comment: @sqlvogel Can you please recommend a few of them? I am open to try some packages that are flexible and easy to integrate with our backend, perhaps Mongo. Thanks!

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Yes. I don't have much experience in this and would like to learn more about how existing systems are tackling this problem. Any resources you would recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

There are a lot of questions here, I'll try to address as many as I can. A lot of the issues are the business model rather than the data model.

Firstly, you are right that you need an immutable invoice. Once an invoice is created you cannot alter it, the standard way of handling a change in invoice is to issue a credit note and a new invoice.

Think about the relations between the tables: the `Order` does not need to hold the `lineItem`s as these are referenced the other way, i.e.

```
Order
=====
orderId
customerId
status

OrderLineItem
=============
orderLineItemId
orderId
product
price
quantity
```

So to view the order you join the tables on orderId. There's also no need to store the `total` as that is calculated from the join.

Try not to duplicate your data: your invoice will reference `orderLineItem`s, but not necessarily the same ones in the order. For example, the customer orders an A and a B, but B is out of stock. You ship A and create an invoice that references `orderLineItemId` for A. So your invoice tables might look like:

```
invoice
=======
invoiceId
status

invoiceLineItem
===============
invoiceId
orderLineItemId
quantity
```

In other words there's no need to have the details of the item. You may be wondering why you don't just add an invoiceId to the orderLineItem table - the reason is the customer might order 10 of item A, but you only ship 8 of them, the other two will go on a subsequent invoice.

Payments are not made against orders, they are against invoices. So your payments table should reference the invoiceId.

Then you touch on reconciliation. If everything was perfect, the customer would make a payment against a particular invoice, even if a partial payment. In reality this is going to be your biggest headache. Suppose the customer has several outstanding invoices for amounts x, y and z. If they make a payment of p, which do you allocate it against? Perhaps in date order, so that if p>x the remainder is allocated against y. What if p=z? Perhaps the customer is intending to pay z now but is disputing y and has mislaid x? How you deal with these sorts of things is up to you, but I can say that most invoicing systems do it very badly indeed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. I got little experience in designing this, and I think I understand what you meant by "they are more related to the business model rather than the data model." But I wonder if I am moving towards a weird direction. So, is it totally normal to have an orderLineItem and a separate invoiceLineItem model? And how they are different depends on the business logic?

Comment: I'm currently working on order/invoice system for a restaurant pos system. Your answer helped a lot. But I've one question: why don't add a field `quantity_fulfilled` to `OrderLineItem` for real delivered order instead of creating `invoiceLineItem` table ?

Comment: @angel It's a year late, but it's because you could have more than one invoice per order (multiple invoice line items per order line item). I would even add a separate mapping table here (order_invoice) to allow the relationship to be many-to-many i.e. multiple invoices per order and multiple orders per invoice.